# Reverse geocoding issues with GT-I9500 samsung s4, version 5.0.1

Tags: android, google-maps

I an doing reverse GeoCoding to get city, state and country name. It is working on all other devices and the same version 5.0.1 as well except "GT-I9500 samsung s4, os version: 5.0.1".

Can anyone faced this issue and suggest me what to do?

```
 public static ArrayList<String> getCityStateCountry(Context context, double latitude, double longitude) {

        ArrayList<String> listCityStateCountryName = new ArrayList<>();


        if (latitude == 0 && longitude == 0) return listCityStateCountryName;


        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                listCityStateCountryName.add(0, addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                listCityStateCountryName.add(1, addresses.get(0).getAdminArea());
                listCityStateCountryName.add(2, addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
            }

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return listCityStateCountryName;
    }
```

This is the code. And not getting any error but list is coming empty.

Comment: Try to debug and post stack trace.

Comment: post some code how you are doing. what error you are getting?

Comment: I have added required information. Please check it.